# When my game object assigns a position of one game object to another game object, it launches off in some direction, without input

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

My game object is fine and its nearby game object is also fine. but the second I say `gameObject1.transform.position = gameObject2.transform.position` it shoots off into space

I feel like my controller isn't so complicated, so I'm going to put the whole thing here for clarity:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Thinkrium;

public class hero_controller : MonoBehaviour
{

/// <summary>
///  temporary
/// </summary>
GameObject current_cart;


public float rotation_percentage = 60;
public float rotation_factor = 5;
private float vertical_motion = 0;
private float horizontal_motion = 0;

public Vector3 adjustable_look_at_offset;

public Vector3 offset_location;

public float push_or_pull_force = 0;
public float camera_location_scalar = 3;

public float lerp_factor = 0.125f;

public Vector3 cart_orientation;

private Vector2 rotation_lock;

private float orientation_switch;


_hero_object hero;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    hero = GameObject.Find("ScriptManager").GetComponent<create_scene>().get_hero();
    offset_location = new Vector3(0, 3.25f, -3);
    adjustable_look_at_offset = new Vector3(0, 1.5F, 0);

    // initially hero will have a cart temporarily
    current_cart = GameObject.Find("pushcart(Clone)");

    rotation_lock.x = current_cart.transform.rotation.x;
    rotation_lock.y = current_cart.transform.rotation.z;


}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    vertical_motion = 0;
    horizontal_motion = 0;

    check_cart_ownership();

    if (hero.request_cart_status())
    {
        hero.is_pushing(observation: true);
        lock_the_shopping_cart();
        //grab_cart();
    }
    else {
        hero.is_pushing(observation: false);
    }

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow)) {

        orientation_switch = 1;
        vertical_motion = 1;
    }
    else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.DownArrow)) {
        orientation_switch = -1;
        vertical_motion = -1;
    }


    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow)) {
        horizontal_motion = -1;
    }
    else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow)) {
        horizontal_motion = 1;
    }



    if (!Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow) && !Input.GetKey(KeyCode.DownArrow)) {
      
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
        {
            hero.should_turn(decision: true);
            hero.turn(this_direction: turning_direction.left);
        }
        else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.F))
        {
            hero.should_turn(decision: true);
            hero.turn(this_direction: turning_direction.right);
        }
        else
        {
            hero.should_turn(decision: false);
        }

    }
    else {

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
        {
            hero.prefab.transform.Rotate(0, -rotation_factor  * orientation_switch, 0);
        }
        else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.F))
        {
            hero.prefab.transform.Rotate(0, rotation_factor  * orientation_switch , 0);
        }

        
    }

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.T)) {
        hero.throw_merch(should_throw: true); ;
    }

    hero.move(horizontal: horizontal_motion, vertical: vertical_motion);

    set_location(for_the: hero.camera);
    set_location(for_the: hero.look_at_target, is_camera: false);

    hero.camera.transform.LookAt(hero.look_at_target.transform);

}

private void set_location(GameObject for_the, bool is_camera = true) {

    float current_rotation;

    if ((int)hero.prefab.transform.localEulerAngles.y > 0) {
        current_rotation = Mathf.Floor((int)hero.prefab.transform.localEulerAngles.y);
    }
    else {
        current_rotation = Mathf.Floor(360 + (int)hero.prefab.transform.rotation.y);
    }


    if (is_camera)
    {
        offset_location.x = hero.prefab.transform.position.x - (camera_location_scalar * Mathf.Sin(current_rotation / rotation_percentage));
        offset_location.z = hero.prefab.transform.position.z - (camera_location_scalar * Mathf.Cos(current_rotation / rotation_percentage));
    }
    else {
        offset_location.x  =  adjustable_look_at_offset.x + hero.prefab.transform.position.x + (camera_location_scalar * Mathf.Sin(current_rotation / rotation_percentage));
        offset_location.y  =  adjustable_look_at_offset.y;
        offset_location.z  =  adjustable_look_at_offset.z + hero.prefab.transform.position.z + (camera_location_scalar * Mathf.Cos(current_rotation / rotation_percentage));
    }


    for_the.transform.position = Vector3.Slerp(for_the.transform.position, offset_location, lerp_factor);

}

public void stop_throwing() {
    hero.stop_throwing_merch();
}

public void grab_cart() {
}


/////////////////////////
///// offending code ////
/////////////////////////

public void lock_the_shopping_cart() {
    current_cart.transform.position = hero.prefab.transform.position;
    current_cart.transform.Rotate(rotation_lock.x, current_cart.transform.rotation.y, rotation_lock.y);
}

public void check_cart_ownership() {
    hero.set_cart_status(cart_status: false);

    //for (int i = 0; i < hero.hand.transform.childCount; i++)
    //{
    //    if (hero.hand.transform.GetChild(i).tag == "shopping_cart")
    //    {
    hero.set_cart_status(cart_status: true);
    //    }
    //}

}
}
```

I don't want to lock the position, I'm trying to think of the most logical thing in real life.

The goal is to push and pull a shopping cart and for it to not move with the hands.

In real life you grab a shopping cart (parent relationship) and the cart moves with you.

That doesn't work so far because even though I can compensate for the rotation of the hands, I would also have to compensate for root motion variations. I can do this, but I'm pretty sure that is more work than necessary.

It seems like there would be a pre-existing method for what I'm doing.

Comment: It's perhaps because when you assign one object to the other object's position, they overlap and collide -- Unity then tries to resolve that collision by pushing them off each other, which can result in fast shooting away of bodies. If that's the case, then either don't move them to the same position, or disable the collision between them using the Physics' dialog layer matrix, or the [Physics.IgnoreCollision](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.IgnoreCollision.html) command. On a sidenote, C# coding conventions prefer camel case `likeThis` instead of underscores `like_this`.

Comment: I know camel case I’ve just always liked that version , moreReadable for me thanks for the suggestion

Comment: What @PhilippLenssen said about the physics part is right; I would like to add that you could try maybe parenting the object to the parent object and remove it's rigidbody, in effect unity will treat it's collider as part of the rigidbody of the parent gameobject; but honestly it really depends on your implementation and what you're trying to achieve